# Understand error with Jest, Enzyme and React using contains

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

The pattern to check if a React component contains something with Enzyme + Jest seems to be this one:

```
expect(shallow(<Field title="hello" />).contains(<p id="hello"></p>)).toBe(true);
```

The main problem I face with this kind of code is that I have no clue what the problem is if the expectation fails. Because it uses the pattern "expect boolean to be boolean", the only error I get is:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false
```

It does not really help. Is there a way to get more precise error when testing if a React element contains something?

Comment: What kind of precision are you talking about? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your comment. I mean: "you expected Field to contain this, and it contains that". In other words, the content, not the booleans that say the content does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are more ways of checking if the element is present within the component. And if your test case fails you can debug the wrapper to check what went wrong. .debug() won't pinpoint the error but I think it will make debugging very easy since you get what is being rendered by shallow/mount.

The following command will help you debug a wrapper.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Field title="hello" />);
console.log(wrapper.debug());
```

I have created a sandbox to demonstrate the same there I use 'contains' and 'find' on the wrapper to check if p is present with id as "hello" and also on the console you can see the output of wrapper.debug()

https://codesandbox.io/s/886799791j